# how can i make shorter my Jagged(Ragged ) code?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, jagged-arrays, ragged

How can i write a shorter code with a for loop, Is it possible? instead of writing;

```
    int array[][] = new int[10][];
    array[0] = new int[1];
    array[1] = new int[2];
    array[2] = new int[3];
    array[3] = new int[4];
    array[4] = new int[5];
    array[5] = new int[6];
    array[6] = new int[7];
    array[7] = new int[8];
    array[8] = new int[9];
    array[9] = new int[10];
```

Here is my code;

```
    int array[][] = new int[10][];
    array[0] = new int[1];
    array[1] = new int[2];
    array[2] = new int[3];
    array[3] = new int[4];
    array[4] = new int[5];
    array[5] = new int[6];
    array[6] = new int[7];
    array[7] = new int[8];
    array[8] = new int[9];
    array[9] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            array[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
            System.out.printf("%-4d",array[i][j]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You seem to be successfully using a `for` loop elsewhere in your code, so what makes it difficult to convert the array creation into a loop?

Comment: i mean how to make combine this loop; for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
      array[k] = new int[k + 1];
  }
with other :/

Comment: Why do you want to combine it with the others?

Comment: To write out of all values as a triangle.

Comment: Did you write the other code yourself?

Comment: yes i wrote myself ( try and fail). It 've almost  token 2 days :D

Comment: I recommend actually thinking about what the code does. It helps to write down the steps. Programming is too complex (even with simple examples like this) to do with just trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic solution, if you decide to change the length of the array

```
int array[][] = new int[10][];

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[i + 1];
}
```

You could also combine the two loops like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[i + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            array[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might trying moving the initialization inside the loop

```
int array[][] = new int[10][];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    array[i] = new int[i + 1];
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        array[i][j] = i + j;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        System.out.printf("%-4d",array[i][j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  array[i] = new int[i + 1]
}
```

or for the mere fun of making it functional (don't ask about other aspects)

```
//just the empty array
int[][] array = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                         .map(i -> i + 1)
                         .mapToObj(int[]::new)
                         .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Or initialize *and* fill the array in functional style:

```
//the array with values
int[][] array = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                         .mapToObj(v -> IntStream.range(v, v + v + 1).toArray())
                         .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

And even do the output this way:

```
String out = Arrays.stream(array)
                   .map(x -> Arrays.stream(x)
                                   .mapToObj(y -> String.format("%-4d", y))
                                   .collect(Collectors.joining()))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: i hust wondering what does  this symbol -> do? I'm a begginer and i'd like to learn. Thank you

Comment: it defines a lambda expression, you could read it "given the value(s) on the left, do the things on the right". I.e. `i -> i + 1` translates to, `given value i, calculate i+1 (and return it, as map() expects return value)`

Answer (score 0):

With java 8:

```
Integer[][] a = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(Collections.nCopies( 10, new Integer[0]  ))
.stream()
.map( p -> new Integer[p.length +1] )
.toArray(size -> new Integer[size][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

code is shorter now thanx :)

```
    int array[][] = new int[10][];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new int[i + 1];

        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) 
        { 
            array[i][j] = i + j;
        }
    }
    for (int[] row : array) 
    {
        for(int k:row)
            System.out.print( k+ " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```